# K-means++ with cosine distance

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, cosine-distance

I am wondering how to implement k-means++ with cosine distance, acording to quote below (wikipedia), which says, that distance needs to be squared. But with square is lost direction of distance which in my understanding really matters.

```
cos_dist(x,y) = -1 => (-1)^2 = 1
```

> 1. Choose one center uniformly at random among the data points.
> 2. For each data point x not chosen yet, compute D(x), the distance between x and the nearest center that has already been chosen.
> 3. Choose one new data point at random as a new center, using a weighted probability distribution where a point x is chosen with
>    probability proportional to D(x)2.
> 4. Repeat Steps 2 and 3 until k centers have been chosen.
> 5. Now that the initial centers have been chosen, proceed using standard k-means clustering.

Comment: You can scale it to $[0,1]$, but how do you compute the centroids?

Answer (score 1):

The intuition is to choose a point that is as far as possible from the existing centers. It does not matter in which direction the new point lies, as long as it is far away.